# Função com parâmetros react native

Tags: react, react-native

Tenho o meu `construtor`:

```
constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            categorias: [],
            refreshing: true
        }

        this.buscarSubcategorias = this.buscarSubcategorias.bind(this);
    }
```

E a função:

```
buscarSubcategorias(categoria_id) {
        alert(categoria_id);
    }
```

E no meu botão eu tenho:

```
<TouchableHighlight key={ item.id } onPress={ () => { this.buscarSubcategorias(item.id) }}>
         <Text style={ styles.txtLinks }>{ item.nome }</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Porém ao clicar recebo o seguinte erro:

> undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this3.buscarSubcategorias(item.id)')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é necessário dar bind na função. Também não é necessário o uso das chaves ao chamar a função:

```
onPress={ () => { this.buscarSubcategorias(item.id) } }
```

Sem elas:

```
onPress={ () => this.buscarSubcategorias(item.id) }
```

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Como você está utilizando de uma arrow function como callback, não é necessário dar um bind no construtor. Remova a linha do bind e provavelmente dará certo.

Comment: Sim, isso responde. Se ele remover o .bind no construtor ele deixa de receber undefined.